# Synchronizing client calls in an xml-rpc-light server in OCaml

Tags: thread-safety, ocaml, xml-rpc

I'm writing an XML-RPC module in OCaml using the [xml-rpc-light](http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpc-light/) library. I'd like to have a server which can receive concurrent requests and gather the data sent by all the requests in a common 'state'. To be concrete, but simplifying the real problem, suppose the server provides the function

```
send : int -> bool
```

which sends an integer and returns true on success and false on failure, and that the server wants to keep a list of all the integers that were ever called since it started (including duplicates).

I understand the XML-RPC part. The part I'm having trouble to implement in OCaml is synchronizing the various client calls on the server side so that they are thread safe.

I've written a client class

```
class client =
    object
        val xr_client = new XmlRpc.client "http://localhost:11111"
        method send n = xr_client#call "send_integer" [`Int n] in
    end
```

which calls the appropriate `send_integer` remote method with some integer `n`.

I've also written a server class

```
class server =
    object(self)
        val mutable state = (ref [] : int list ref)
        val xr_server = new XmlRpcServer.netplex ()
        val m = Mutex.create ()
        method send n =
            let send_sync s n = (Mutex.lock m; s := n::!s; Mutex.unlock m) in
            (send_sync state n; `Boolean true)
        method init () =
            xr_server#register "send_integer"
                ~signatures:[[`Int; `Boolean]]
                (function
                   | [`Int x] -> self#send x;
                   | _ -> XmlRpcServer.invalid_params ());
            xr_server#run ()    
    end
```

which has a mutable `state` to keep all the integers and a `send` method to actually execute the client calls. For each client call, I just update the state. But if a second call comes before the second is finished, I run into thread safety problems. That's why I've added the `Mutex` bit which uses a single class field mutex to acquire a lock on updating the state.

My questions are:

1. Would synchronization be achieved by this?
2. Are there neater ways of doing it?
3. Is synchronization built-in in the XML-RPC server already, making all of this unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After solving [compilation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784928/ocamlbuild-fails-to-compile-complaining-implementation-of-netsys-is-not-provided) with this code, I realised that we can't use the threads library together with xmlrpc-light; at least directly. So, we can't use the `Mutex` module anyway.

Synchronisation is obtained by configuring the XML-RPC server to allow only **one thread** at a time during runtime. This can be achieved by providing our server with a configuration file similar to the [adder example](http://code.google.com/p/saastafi/source/browse/trunk/utils/votecalc/xmlrpc-light-0.6/examples/adder/adder.conf?r=266) but setting `max_threads = 1` in the last line. If we allow, say, 2 threads, then sometimes the change is made in the mutable state of one thread, sometimes it is made in the mutable state of the other.