# OCamlbuild fails to compile complaining implementation of Netsys is not provided when it is

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'm trying to compile an XML-RPC server written using the [xmlrpc-light library](http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpc-light/) in OCaml with ocamlbuild but I get:

```
$ ocamlbuild server.native
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -package xmlrpc-light -package unix -package threads -package netsys -thread server.cmx -o server.native
File "_none_", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Netsys referenced from /usr/lib/ocaml/equeue/equeue.cmxa(Uq_engines)
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 4 targets (3 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

Note that I have a `myocamlbuild.ml` file like [this one](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Using_ocamlfind_with_ocamlbuild#Source) and a `_tags` file containing a single line:

```
<server.ml> or <server.native>: pkg_unix,pkg_netsys,pkg_xmlrpc-light,pkg_threads
```

This plugin has worked fine for me in other cases (for `client.native` of the same client/server application, for example) but not for `server.native`. The complaint suggests that the library Netsys is not available to the compiler. But we get

```
$ ocamlfind query netsys
/usr/lib/ocaml/netsys
```

meaning that netsys is installed in `/usr/lib/ocaml/netsys`. Inspecting that directory gives me:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/ocaml/netsys
META  libnetsys.a  netsys.a  netsys.cma  netsys.cmi  netsys.cmxa  netsys.mli
```

Also,

```
$ ocamlfind list | grep netsys
netsys              (version: 2.2.9)
```

So, there is indeed a library called netsys installed, it does have a cmxa file ready to be used, but for some strange reason, ocamlbuild complaints that there is no implementation provided for the module Netsys. The fact that ocamlbuild could read `/usr/lib/ocaml/equeue/equeue.cmxa` should be enough to conclude that everything should be fine regarding environment ($PATH, etc.) in terms of finding libraries.

This is all in Debian 6.0 and my OCaml's version is 3.11.2.

After some browsing, I found an [svn commit message](http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpc-light/source/detail?spec=svn139&r=57) ([repository diff](http://code.google.com/p/xmlrpc-light/source/diff?spec=svn139&r=57&format=side&path=/trunk/examples/adder/Makefile)) which suggests that it may have to do with the number of threads used. And, in fact, I'm using a Mutex somewhere in my code (check the code of `server.ml` and `client.ml` in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605404/synchronizing-client-calls-in-an-xml-rpc-light-server-in-ocaml)). If I remove the Mutex stuff from my `server.ml` the error still happens. But if I additionally remove the `pkg_threads` from the `_tags` file then everything compiles. So, my conclusion is that I can't directly use the threads library with `xmlrpc-light`, which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO equeue META is wrong. Adding netsys to dependencies fixes your issue :

```
sed -i 's/threads/netsys,threads/' /usr/lib/ocaml/equeue/META
```